# was emailed some attachments, is this html/css with odt.file suspicious?

Tags: security, download, html

someone sent me this email, he said he wanted to submit articles to sites for the purpose of 'whitehat seo'
i was helping him with his english so the articles would sound more coherent and be useful for whatever site.
so he asks if he can send me a file with his essay for me to edit.
i had a linux box with me that i occasionally reinstall OS on, so i opened it up, intending to analyze from my mac when i got home.
some of the text in the article is a hyperlink, but i am not sure if that is the intent of SEO or a malicious download.
it looks like this when i use firebug to 'inspect the element' before downloading:

ahref="?ui=2&ik=98e0cb699b&view=att&th=12d974888baada2e&attid=0.1&disp=attd&zw">Download>

that is the link in the text, i thought it was weird it had the download tag.
so is this a legitimate thing?
or is this questionable?
that is the hyperlink embedded in the text, the rest looks fairly basic, afaik
he sent me an email with attached file (through gmail, which scans for executables/malware, i think)
then sent me an email with a legitamate link to ezine#rticlesdotcom
standard seo practice, or something else?

Comment: If what we see on the page is what the actual code is, and it's not garbled somehow on superuser, the link is harmless because it is malformed.  Malformed in a non-malicious way.  It won't open anything.

Comment: it is slightly altered...it doesnt seem malformed in the document, i could click to go to the site but am hesitant to do that...

Comment: i dont know why the answer was voted up, i dont think it really matters what type of container.  is it normal for embedded links to have 'Download' tag in whitehat SEO

Answer (score 1):

(Your post is garbled, please correct it.)

ODT files are created by Writer, the OpenOffice.org and StarOffice word processor, and are formatted using the OASIS OpenDocument XML-based standard.